# Opencart Multi Store login with same store customer not others

Tags: authentication, opencart, multistore

I am using opencart Multi store , as per my code we are having up to 10 stores , every store we have customers , the customers who is registered with particular store he can able to login to that store only, if he tries to login with any other store which he not registered there must be a error message like you are not registered with this store or else something else...
as per my code if customer login with other store which not registered he is redirecting to his store only but not login, it should not redirect and he should get error message...

Below is my controller :

```
<?php
class ControllerAccountLogin extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
    //echo 44; exit;
        $this->load->model('account/customer');

        // Login override for admin users
        if (!empty($this->request->get['token'])) {
            $this->event->trigger('pre.customer.login');

            $this->customer->logout();
            $this->cart->clear();

            unset($this->session->data['wishlist']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_address']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_address']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
            unset($this->session->data['comment']);
            unset($this->session->data['order_id']);
            unset($this->session->data['coupon']);
            unset($this->session->data['reward']);
            unset($this->session->data['voucher']);
            unset($this->session->data['vouchers']);

            $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomerByToken($this->request->get['token']);

            if ($customer_info && $this->customer->login($customer_info['email'], '', true)) {
                // Default Addresses
                $this->load->model('account/address');

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'payment') {
                    $this->session->data['payment_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'shipping') {
                    $this->session->data['shipping_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
                }

                $this->event->trigger('post.customer.login');

                $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
            }
        }

        if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
        }

        $this->load->language('account/login');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        //echo $this->config->get('config_store_id'); exit;
          if ($this->config->get('config_store_id')) {
        //  echo 'sravz';
        // echo $this->customer->getStoreId(); exit;
          if ($this->customer->getStoreId() != 0) {
        if ($this->customer->getStoreId() != $this->config->get('config_store_id')) {
            $this->load->model('setting/store');
           // $store_info = $this->model_setting_store->getStore($this->customer->getStoreId());
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "store where store_id=".$this->customer->getStoreId()."");
        $store_info = $query->row;
            $this->response->redirect($store_info['url']);
        }
    }

    } 
            unset($this->session->data['guest']);

            // Default Shipping Address
            $this->load->model('account/address');

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'payment') {
                $this->session->data['payment_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'shipping') {
                $this->session->data['shipping_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
            }

            // Add to activity log
            $this->load->model('account/activity');

            $activity_data = array(
                'customer_id' => $this->customer->getId(),
                'name'        => $this->customer->getFirstName() . ' ' . $this->customer->getLastName()
            );

            $this->model_account_activity->addActivity('login', $activity_data);

            // Added strpos check to pass McAfee PCI compliance test (http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=12043&p=151494#p151295)
            if (isset($this->request->post['redirect']) && (strpos($this->request->post['redirect'], $this->config->get('config_url')) !== false || strpos($this->request->post['redirect'], $this->config->get('config_ssl')) !== false)) {
                $this->response->redirect(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $this->request->post['redirect']));
            } else {
                $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
            }
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_account'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_login'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL')
        );

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $data['text_new_customer'] = $this->language->get('text_new_customer');
        $data['text_register'] = $this->language->get('text_register');
        $data['text_register_account'] = $this->language->get('text_register_account');
        $data['text_returning_customer'] = $this->language->get('text_returning_customer');
        $data['text_i_am_returning_customer'] = $this->language->get('text_i_am_returning_customer');
        $data['text_forgotten'] = $this->language->get('text_forgotten');

        $data['entry_email'] = $this->language->get('entry_email');
        $data['entry_password'] = $this->language->get('entry_password');

        $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');
        $data['button_login'] = $this->language->get('button_login');

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL');
        $data['register'] = $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL');
        $data['forgotten'] = $this->url->link('account/forgotten', '', 'SSL');

        // Added strpos check to pass McAfee PCI compliance test (http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=12043&p=151494#p151295)
        if (isset($this->request->post['redirect']) && (strpos($this->request->post['redirect'], $this->config->get('config_url')) !== false || strpos($this->request->post['redirect'], $this->config->get('config_ssl')) !== false)) {
            $data['redirect'] = $this->request->post['redirect'];
        } elseif (isset($this->session->data['redirect'])) {
            $data['redirect'] = $this->session->data['redirect'];

            unset($this->session->data['redirect']);
        } else {
            $data['redirect'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->session->data['success'])) {
            $data['success'] = $this->session->data['success'];

            unset($this->session->data['success']);
        } else {
            $data['success'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
            $data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
        } else {
            $data['email'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['password'])) {
            $data['password'] = $this->request->post['password'];
        } else {
            $data['password'] = '';
        }

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['account'] = $this->load->controller('module/account');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/account/login.tpl')) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/account/login.tpl', $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/account/login.tpl', $data));
        }
    }

    protected function validate() {
        //echo $this->request->post['email'];exit;
        $this->event->trigger('pre.customer.login');

        // Check how many login attempts have been made.
        $login_info = $this->model_account_customer->getLoginAttempts($this->request->post['email']);

        if ($login_info && ($login_info['total'] >= $this->config->get('config_login_attempts')) && strtotime('-1 hour') < strtotime($login_info['date_modified'])) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_attempts');
        }

        // Check if customer has been approved.
        $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomerByEmail($this->request->post['email']);
//print_r($customer_info);exit;
        if ($customer_info && !$customer_info['approved']) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_approved');
        }
//print_r( $this->error); exit;
        if (!$this->error) {
            if (!$this->customer->login($this->request->post['email'], $this->request->post['password'])) {
            //echo 44; exit;    
                           // $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_login');

            //  $this->model_account_customer->addLoginAttempt($this->request->post['email']);
            } else {
                $this->model_account_customer->deleteLoginAttempts($this->request->post['email']);

                $this->event->trigger('post.customer.login');
            }
        }

        return !$this->error;
    }
}
```

Below is my View :

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <?php if ($success) { ?>
  <div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> <?php echo $success; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6 no-pad'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">

    <div class="top">
     <div class="panel-heading title-heading search-head"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">

     <!--  <h2></h2>-->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
         <b style="margin-bottom: 2px; display: block;"><?php echo $text_new_customer; ?></b>
          <div class="well left">

          <!--  <p><strong><?php echo $text_register; ?></strong></p>-->
            <p><?php echo $text_register_account; ?></p>

           <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo "Go to Shopping"; ?></a> --></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <b style="margin-bottom: 2px; display: block;"><?php echo $text_returning_customer; ?></b>
          <div class="well">
          <!--  <h2><?php echo $text_returning_customer; ?></h2>-->
            <p><?php echo $text_i_am_returning_customer; ?></p>
            <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="input-email">  <strong> <?php echo $entry_email; ?></strong></label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_email; ?>" id="input-email" class="form-control" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label" for="input-password">  <strong> <?php echo $entry_password; ?></strong></label></strong>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_password; ?>" id="input-password" class="form-control" />
                <a href="<?php echo $forgotten; ?>"><?php echo $text_forgotten; ?></a></div>
              <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_login; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" />
              <?php if ($redirect) { ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $redirect; ?>" />
              <?php } ?>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div></div>
      <div class="clearfix hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
    <?php echo $column_right; ?>
    <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><div class="container"><?php echo $account; ?></div></div>
</div>
</div>
    <?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To give back an error message to the customer you must check that the customer is part of the Customer Group assigned to that store. Use this at the start of the `validate()` method in `catalog/controller/account/login.php`:

```
$customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomerByEmail($this->request->post['email']);
$customerGroupId = isset($customer_info['customer_group_id']) ? $customer_info['customer_group_id'] : -1;
$allowedCustomerGroups = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display');
if(!is_array($allowedCustomerGroups) || !in_array($customerGroupId, $allowedCustomerGroups)) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_login');
        return false;
}
```

Remember that this will not take care if your customer logs in into the right store and then goes to another store.

If you want to log customer out when they change store use this code and paste after the `$data` variable declaration in `catalog/controller/common/header.php` at around line 90:

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged() && ($this->config->get('config_store_id') != $this->customer->getStoreId())) {
      $this->url->link('account/logout', '', true);
      $this->customer->logout();
}
```

Then

You will have to add this method in the `system/library/cart/customer.php` file:

```
public function getStoreId() {
    return $this->store_id; 
}
```

Hope this helps :)